# List of socks4/5 proxies in a plain text

Tags: internet

I'm looking for list of public socks proxies in the plain text or another format which can be imported via `curl`.

I have tried extract it using script such as:

```
$ pup -f <(curl -sL https://www.socks-proxy.net/) '#proxylisttable tr td:nth-child(1),td:nth-child(2) text{}'
```

but it doesn't work as expected, so I'm looking for alternative open data which should be kept up-to-date in easy to read format.

---

Similar to how I could extract my IP address, like:

```
$ curl ifconfig.co
192.168.0.x
```

or:

```
$ curl ifconfig.co/json
{"ip":"192.168.0.x","ip_decimal":1406000000,"country":"X","country_iso":"GB","city":"Y","hostname":"example.com"}
```

The proxy list should be either in XML/HTML, CSV, JSON, YAML or in the plain text like:

```
x.x.x.x:xxxx
y.y.y.y:yyyy
z.z.z.z:zzzz
```

Comment: List of tor proxies (doesn't appear to be official, but should work): https://torstatus.blutmagie.de/

Answer (score 1):

#### [My-Proxy](https://www.my-proxy.com/)

My-Proxy provides free sock proxies in the plain text updated every hour.

Here is the `curl` command to download it into plain format:

- [Socks 4 list](https://www.my-proxy.com/free-socks-4-proxy.html)

  ```
  curl -A Mozilla -sL "http://www.my-proxy.com/free-socks-4-proxy.html" | egrep -o '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,5}'
  ```

  or:

  ```
  pup -f <(curl -sL http://www.my-proxy.com/free-socks-4-proxy.html) ".list text{}" | awk -F# '{print $1}'
  ```
- [Socks 5 list](https://www.my-proxy.com/free-socks-5-proxy.html)

  ```
  curl -A Mozilla -sL "http://www.my-proxy.com/free-socks-5-proxy.html" | egrep -o '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,5}'
  ```

  or:

  ```
  pup -f <(curl -sL http://www.my-proxy.com/free-socks-4-proxy.html) ".list text{}" | awk -F# '{print $1}'
  ```

Answer (score 1):

#### [GatherProxy](http://www.gatherproxy.com/)

Table of free proxy list. This can be extracted to the plain text by using [`pup` command](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup):

```
pup -f <(curl -sL 'http://www.gatherproxy.com/sockslist') "script text{}" | paste -d: - - | egrep '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' | grep -o "'[^']\+'" | paste -d: - - | tr -d "'"
```